# Vectorize Assign Function

Tags: r

I have a lot of matrices to initialize and i was wondering if I can do it without a loop

I'm trying the following but it doesn't seem to work.  For example

```
resmatrix =c('amatrix','bmatrix','cmatrix')
```

I tried

```
Vectorize(assign,'x')(x=resmatrix,value=matrix(NA,nrow=10,ncol=100))
sapply(resmatrix,FUN=function(x){assign(x,matrix(NA,nrow=10,ncol=100))})
```

Both run but I don't get amatrix/bmatrix/cmatrix variables

Comment: Why do you need to do this? A `list` or an `array` would be a better option. Something like: `setNames(replicate(length(resmatrix), matrix(NA, 10, 100), FALSE), resmatrix)`. But if you really want to have a bunch of matrices in your environment, then you can maybe try: `invisible(sapply(resmatrix, assign, matrix(NA, 10, 100), envir = .GlobalEnv))`.

Comment: And note that if it is just a few matrices you are creating, you can actually just do something like `amatrix <- bmatrix <- cmatrix <- matrix(NA, 10, 100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is a duplicate, there's another concept in your question that is worth mentioning: `assign` needs to know where you want to create the objects.

Thus, assuming you want the results in your global environment, you can rewrite either of your approaches in the following manner:

```
Vectorize(assign, "x", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)(resmatrix, matrix(NA, 10, 10), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

and

```
sapply(resmatrix, assign, matrix(NA, 10, 100), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Wrap the above with `invisible()` if you don't need to see the output, but just need to assign the objects.

---

A better option, however, would be to keep this all in a `list` or an `array` and work with those structures instead.

For example:

```
setNames(replicate(length(resmatrix), matrix(NA, 10, 100), FALSE), resmatrix)
```